# Does this prove that the derivative (known to exist) needs to be positive?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

A continuous and differentiable function $F(\mathbf{k}):\Bbb R_+^m\to \Bbb R_+$ is such that

- $\mathbf{k}\in I\subset\Bbb R_+^m\Longleftrightarrow F(\mathbf{k})\geq 1$
- $\mathbf{k}\not\in I\subset\Bbb R_+^m\Longleftrightarrow F(\mathbf{k})< 1$
- $\mathbf{k}\in O\subset I\Longrightarrow F(\mathbf{k})=1$.

In fact, $O$ is part of the boundary of $I$. Let $\langle O\rangle$ denote the cone spanned by $O$ (i.e., $\mathbf{k}\in O\implies \lambda\mathbf{k}\in\langle O\rangle\;\forall\lambda>0$) and $\DeclareMathOperator{\setint}{relint}\setint \langle O\rangle$ denote its relative interior. Consider $\mathbf{k}\in O\cap\setint \langle O\rangle$, choose $\gamma\in \Bbb R$ and consider $\mathbf{k}'=\mathbf{k}+\gamma\mathbf{e}_j$, where $\mathbf{e}_j$ is a vector of zeros except for a one at position $j$. It is known that $\mathbf{k}'\not\in O$, and that

- $\gamma>0\implies\mathbf{k}'\in I$
- $\gamma<0\implies\mathbf{k}'\not\in I$

I believe that this allows me to write

$$
\lim_{\gamma\to 0}\frac{F(\mathbf{k}')-F(\mathbf{k})}{\gamma}>0
$$
and, therefore, to claim that

$$
   \frac{dF(\mathbf{k})}{dk_j}>0\quad\forall\mathbf{k}\in O\cap\setint \langle O\rangle\text{ and }\forall j\in\{1,2,\dots m\}.
$$

Am I right?

$F(\mathbf{k})$ is the result of a constrained maximization problem, so the derivatives I'm trying to sign are just the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker multipliers which, by definition, are non-negative in all the domain. I believe that all of them should be strictly positive in subset $O\cap\setint \langle O\rangle$.